# Django REST browser interface

Tags: python, django, web-services, testing, rest

I'm writing a set of REST services for a Django project. I've been using django-rest-framework for a while. Because of its limited functionality I had to switch to django-piston which I quite enjoy.

However, django-rest-framework had one really nice feature - it was able to display an admin-like interface for testing the created services from the browser. It's just terrific for debugging purposes. It's very simple: one form is displayed for each HTTP method like "GET", "POST", etc. Along with that a drop-down list of available content types and a text field for putting in the data to be sent.

As I view it, this isn't really a feature in any way directly connected with a particular REST framework. It isn't even necessarily about Django. It could all be achieved just using HTML + JS, or an external website.

My question is: What do you use for manual testing / debugging web services? Could you point me to some HTML snippet or a Django app that would do the described thing?

Comment: I had the same problem, that was solved by logging out of Admin page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may seem obvious, but: 
Why not just use Django's testing client (django.test.client.Client)? then instead of manually  'debugging' in your browser, you can write unit tests with expectations and get leverage out of those further down the track.

e.g.

```
from django.test.client import Client
client = Client()
resp = client.put('/employee/2/', data={'email': 'here@there.com'}, follow=True)
#... etc
```

Comment: Well, maybe you're right. I'll take that into consideration. maybe it's just my bad habit from the dark times of Java code writing where preparing any unit tests was a pain.

Comment: That made me chuckle :P (I know your pain). The django test client is fantastic and simple to use. I use for 'exploratory' interactive sessions in my shell (IPython) and then later turn my session's history into something reusable for testing.

Comment: Does this pull out the "2" and pass it as an arg to the view as determined by the urlconf?

Answer (score 3):

As the author of django-rest-framework it'd be great to pick your brains about which bits of functionality could do with fleshing out. :) (obv i've got some thoughts of my own and areas I'm planning to work on, but be really good to get some user perspective)

Your absolutely right about the API browser not being limited to any particular framework. To me that's the big deal with DRF and I'd love to see more API frameworks take a similar approach. One of the supposed benefits of RESTful APIs is that they should be self-describing, and it seems counter-intuitive to me that so many of the Web APIs we build today are not Web browseable.

Oh, and totally agree with jsw re. testing Web APIs in django, I wouldn't use the framework's browsable API to replace automated tests.

Comment: Well as far as I could tell there isn't really any support for foreign key joins. I find this feature the most difficult to actually implement by hand, so I was really looking forward to having it done for me. As for the GUI part, I loved it, and still miss it.

Comment: Maybe I'll just clarify - I really liked what you've written. Despite the early version it behaved very stable. I had no issues. The documentation is decent. If it were not for those foreign keys I think I'd definitely use it. It think it has potential to become "the" restful solution for Django.

Comment: Not sure about the etiquette of cross-posting a question from me here, but, you might be the best person to offer some insight on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752748/implementing-restful-servers-with-django-for-dojos-jsonreststore-which-tools-f

Comment: @julkiewicz thanks for the feedback! I probably need to take a closer look at the various ways of handling related models.  Might try to pick your brains again once I've had a bit of time to look through it.

Comment: @julkiewicz Update: as of 0.2.3, we've now got really nice support for nested Resources and handling FK and M2M fields.  I could really do with updating some of the docs with the latest functionality, but it's all there now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and that was eaily solved by logging out of admin page in that project.